# Magento 2: Local site URL doubling up

Tags: magento2, url, 404

Sorry, the title is kind of vague but I've never seen this problem before. I have my local site URL set to be dev.testsite.dev but when entering that address in a web browser it automatically forwards it to

> dev.testsite.dev/dev.testsite.dev/index.php/?SID=95tsurjsja8ci9baihj94oado6

causing the page to 404 along with all of the content it's attempting to fetch like the CSS. I can answer any necessary questions but I've gone through most of the basic troubleshooting steps with no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check Magentos base URLs. They should start with `http://` or `https://`, otherwise it's like a relative path that can cause this.